# How can i fix max redirect issue in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

My scripts was working fine but now it starts showing that max redirects are more than the limit set up in jmeter.properties file.How can it be possible as before it was not throwing any error before and script was passing perfectly.Can anyone help me with that.

Comment: Perhaps a bit more data about your request?   Did you look at the request using the listener 'View Results Tree' to see what the response headers look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter default maximum redirects count is **5**.

It is controllable via `httpsampler.max_redirects` property. You can increase its value using one of the following options:

1. Uncomment `#httpsampler.max_redirects=5` line in *jmeter.properties* file. The file lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation. Property change implies JMeter restart.
2. Add `httpsampler.max_redirects=N` line to *user.properties* file (same location, /bin folder of your JMeter installation). Set "N" value to desired number of redirects. Again, JMeter restart will be required.
3. Pass this property via `-J` command line argument as

   ```
   jmeter -Jhttpsampler.max_redirects=20`
   ```

For more information on different JMeter properties and options on manipulating them refer to [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri.but is already set up and I was not getting any problem but only sometimes I get it.my concern is why it is giving that error as redirects are not changing,they are same

Answer (score 1):

1. Navigate to /bin directory of your J Meter installation.
2. Locate j meter properties file and open it in any editor.
3. Search for “ HTTP sampler. max_redirects” property in opened file.
4. UN-comment the above property by removing # before it.
5. Change to value to more than 5 e.g. 50.
6. Save the file and restart J Meter.